# iPad safari crashes on parsing path string in raphael.js

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, raphael

I'm trying to draw a few path objects that I exported (save as SVG) from Adobe Illustrator in raphael.js. The path(s) look(s) like this:

```
'M31.181-56.886l5.08,34.108l1.643,0.947v0l0,0l0,0v0l5.252-3.032l-6.164-41.371l4.14-41.301l-0.001,0L3.95-129l-5.149,2.243v0.001l-4.216,42.073l-31.67,18.284v44.931l1.644,0.948l5.188-2.994v-32.951h0.001l28.708,16.574V-0.95L0.096,0l5.189-2.996v-38.941L31.181-56.886 M2.99-102.084l29.241,16.883l-1.537,15.331L1.455-86.751L2.99-102.084'
```

or

```
'M-12.385-52.752l6.252,49.204L0.017,0h0.001L1.94-1.11l-6.253-49.202l34.379-19.847l5.412,42.587l6.148,3.551l1.924-1.11l-7.217-56.773l4.844-42.761L35.149-129l-40.193,23.206L-12.385-52.752z M28.527-86.413L14.73-94.378l0.001,0l15.729-9.082l-1.932,17.047Z',
```

These Strings get parsed perfectly fine on all desktop browsers, yet in Safari on iOS the page will hang on parsing them and cause Safari to "force-close" after a while.

I am drawing them like:

```
Layers.elementsOfTypeA.path(this.path).attr(Styles.whiteTransparent);
```

Is this a problem with iOS and/or raphael.js or are my path strings somehow malformed? Unfortunately I am on a PC and do have no possibility to access any kind of console information / errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have no Ipad, so I can't try, but I think you can solve this with [this Paper.safari method](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.safari) from the raphael references.

Best